# scraping JS failed even after using chromium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this website:

https://www.izkor.gov.il/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A8/en_399451c07d6af2edbb259e94a77362b2

I've tried this:

```
first_fallen_url = r'https://www.izkor.gov.il/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A8/en_399451c07d6af2edbb259e94a77362b2'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(first_fallen_url)

resp = requests.get(first_fallen_url)
html = resp.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

with open("page_example.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

But the resulting website is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

first_fallen_url = r'https://www.izkor.gov.il/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A8/en_399451c07d6af2edbb259e94a77362b2'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(first_fallen_url)
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="lxml")

with open("page_example.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))

driver.close()
```

Comment: Yes!!  what was my mistake? just didn't wait long enough?

Comment: Yep. That was *one of the mistakes*. But the major mistake was that you opened the website using `selenium` but u used `requests` to scrape the html code.